# Retrieve a path of a file in specific commit in Git

Tags: git, github, logging, show, filepath

I have a list of commit id and filenames from a git repository. what I need is to get the file path of each file in the list based on the commit id. But I don't know how to do that using git command.

Suppose I have a commit id and filename: `[cb85815bc1, GuiCommonElements.java]`. 
Now I need the full path of the file in that commit id. So, the output should be like `path/path/path/GuiCommonElements.java`.

I tried many commands but didn't give me such results.

```
git show cb85815bc1 --grep='GuiCommonElements.java'
git log cb85815bc1 --grep='GuiCommonElements.java' --name-only
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What if that commit has four different file paths, all of which either end with or contain that path component? E.g., what if commit `cb85815bc1` contains `d1/GuiCommonElements.java`, `d2/GuiCommonElements.java`, `lib/old/GuiCommonElements.java`, and `lib/new/GuiCommonElements.java`?

Comment: @torek All paths should be retrieved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git show` (or `git log -p`, which does something extremely similar but operates on more than one commit) will *diff* the commit against its parent(s).  Adding `--name-only` reduces the diff output to show only changed-file-names, rather than changed-file-names plus the instruction-set.

What you probably want here is to use `git ls-tree`, which shows the names of files contained within a commit.  If you are not at the top level of the repository, `git ls-tree` defaults to showing only things in the current directory, so you probably want to add `-r --full-tree`.  You then want to look for things that contain, or end with, your selected name:

```
git ls-tree -r --full-tree cb85815bc1 | grep GuiCommonElements.java
```

This is slightly flawed as `grep` itself takes regular expression arguments and shows lines that match, so not only will it show files like:

```
lib/old/GuiCommonElements.java
lib/new/GuiCommonElements.java
```

but also:

```
other/ThisIsNotGuiCommonElements.java
```

(because that *contains* `GuiCommonElements.java`) and:

```
other/GuiCommonElementsXJava
```

(because `.` matches one of any character, including `X`).  But it's probably good enough, and if you like, you can shore it up a bit.

The [`git ls-tree` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree) claims that it takes `<path>...` arguments that are "patterns to match", but glob patterns seem not to work here:  If globs worked, `'**/GuiCommonElements.java'` would do the trick, but in my test just now they didn't.